# clang libtooling: PPCallbacks only for defines in main source file

Tags: clang, libtooling

I want to retrieve macro names within a source file but avoid the ones that are defined within included header files. 
Right now I am using

> PPCallbacks::MacroDefined

to get the macro token.

Is there a way to skip this callback when defined macro is within some included header file?

Answer (score 1):

The `MacroDefined` method of
[`PPCallbacks`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html)
is passed a
[`MacroDirective`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1MacroDirective.html),
which has a `getLocation` method that yields a
[`SourceLocation`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html).
That is the location where the macro is defined.

You can pass that location to the
`isWrittenInMainFile` method of
[`SourceManager`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html)
to check if it is defined in the main source file.

Beware: There is also `isInMainFile` (no `Written`), which works a
little differently.  In clang+llvm-14 at least, the latter method
reports `true` for predefined macros as well as those in the main file,
which seems like a bug to me.

To demonstrate filtering for macros defined in the main file, I modified the
[`pp-trace`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/pp-trace.html) program
included in the `clang-tools-extra` package so it only reports
`MacroDefinition`s in the main file:

```
--- a/PPCallbacksTracker.cpp
+++ b/PPCallbacksTracker.cpp
@@ -336,9 +336,15 @@ void PPCallbacksTracker::MacroExpands(const Token &MacroNameTok,
 // Hook called whenever a macro definition is seen.
 void PPCallbacksTracker::MacroDefined(const Token &MacroNameTok,
                                       const MacroDirective *MacroDirective) {
+  SourceLocation loc = MacroDirective->getLocation();
+  if (!PP.getSourceManager().isWrittenInMainFile(loc)) {
+    return;  // skip
+  }
+
   beginCallback("MacroDefined");
   appendArgument("MacroNameTok", MacroNameTok);
   appendArgument("MacroDirective", MacroDirective);
+  appendArgument("Location", loc.printToString(PP.getSourceManager()));
 }
 
 // Hook called whenever a macro #undef is seen.
```

This change also causes the output to report the location of each
defined macro.  You should be able to grab the sources for `pp-trace`,
apply this diff, and see the behavior.  Or just add the `if` test to
your own code.

Example run:

```
$ cat test.cpp
// test.cpp
// Simple test of pp-trace-mod.exe

// Pull in a few macros.
#include <stddef.h>

// Define a macro in the main file.
#define MY_MACRO 0

int main()
{
  return MY_MACRO;
}

// EOF

$ ./pp-trace-mod.exe  --extra-arg=-I/home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/lib/clang/14.0.0/include --callbacks=MacroDefined test.cpp
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "test.cpp"
No compilation database found in /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/pp-trace-mod or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
---
- Callback: MacroDefined
  MacroNameTok: MY_MACRO
  MacroDirective: MD_Define
  Location: /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/pp-trace-mod/test.cpp:8:9
...
```

Observe that the only macro definition reported is the one in the main
file, even though `stddef.h` defines a bunch too.